# ZendFrameWork how to connect with Zend_Db_Adapter_Driver_Pdo

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
$params = array('host'=> 'localhost',
                'username'  => 'root',
                'password'    => '',
                'dbname'        => 'test'
               );

$DB = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Driver_Pdo($params);
$DB->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
Zend_Registry::set('DB',$DB);
```

in my Bootstrap can't connect to the database because i don't know how to write the

```
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo;
```

it says class Zend_Db_Adapter_Driver_Pdo not found

Comment: Refer : http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html

Comment: third question about zendframework database... I really suggest you read some tutorials or a book.

Comment: Are you using ZF2 or ZF1? Use underscore (_) or slash (\) according your framework version and don't mix.

Answer (score 0):

Make the connection in your application.ini:

```
//excerpt from application.ini
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Database Settings
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resources.db.adapter = "pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.username = "user"
resources.db.params.password = "xxxxxx"
resources.db.params.dbname = "database"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```

then in your bootstrap you can add all of the application.ini settings to the registry:

```
//Bootstrap.php
protected function _initRegistry()
    {
        $config = new Zend_Config($this->getOptions());
        Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
    }
```

***Natrium*** is correct you need to do a lot more research into Zend Framework 1.x. You are not going to figure this out on the fly. This framework is not trivial in scope or application.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the following code

1) In your application.ini file, add the following

```
db.adapter = pdo_Mysql
db.params.host = host_name
db.params.username = user_name
db.params.password = pasword
db.params.dbname = database_name
db.params.profiler = true
```

2) Next, in your index.php file, add the following

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

// auto loader
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

// config
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', 'production');
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->set('config', $config);

// setup database
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->db);
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
$registry->set('db', $db);
```

Hopefully, this will help you.